# Trigger cloud function when a specific condition resulting from the comparison of document fields in firestore is true

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In the observed document there are 2 fields that include timestamps, `tsA` and `tsB`.
`tsA` moves progressively closer to `tsB` until they eventually are the same - when this happens a cloud function shall be triggered, which performs a database operation in Firestore.
Is it possible to implement something like that - if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot trigger a function when a specific condition is met in Firestore. You can use [`onUpdate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) trigger and then compare the values in the function itself.

If this operation doesn't need to be realtime then you can run a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) (every few minutes/hours) that'll query for all documents where `tsA` and `tsB` are same and then process them.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise answer!